# How to search after assembly problems or documentations?

Tags: discussion

I'm pretty new to assembly and I know there are some standards but if I search for specifics problems with my assembly code I often find only some answers for other architectures. But I'm not sure how I should search for my architecture. There are some many different assembly dialects out there that I'm totally confused and I don't have any specific documentation for my architecture.

Does there exist something like general documentation, which is not dialect specific?
Does anyone know how to exactly search for a question on stack-overflow? Do I have to add some specific tags or something? Or is there probably something like an assembly stack community?

Comment: How and where do you search? Its still the best option to use a proper search engine such as Google to find answers on Stack Overflow. If you name the dialect then someone can probably point you to a site with a complete reference. Heck, sometimes even Wikipedia lists such sites.

Comment: Do you mean "assembly code" as used in for example an [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) type of CPU? Or perhaps [webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webassembly) ?

Comment: When using Google to search, you can still write `site:stackoverflow.com` to just show results from this site, so like "how to assemble assembly site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Do you know what architecture you are writing assembler code for? I would suggest searching using the architecture as a keyword, As you point out, each assembly language is different.

Answer (score -1):

The search terms for an assembly language problem would be `assembler <canonical abbreviation for your architecture> <search terms for your problem>`.

In Google, you could add `site:stackoverflow.com` to search specifically on SO but given the scarcity of assembler materials and the existence of niche specialized sites on them, there's no real need to.